# Bootstrapping java and python compilers

Tags: java, python, compiler-construction, bootstrapping

The wikipedia page on [compiler bootstrapping](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) lists python and java among the languages whose compilers are bootstrapped. Aren't javac and cpython implemented in c? 
Why are these languages listed on that page?

Comment: That which creates the self-hosted bootstrap version (let's call it genesis) is written in another language. This is often C or Assembler.

Comment: [JikesRVM](http://www.jikesrvm.org/) provides a Java-compiler written in Java. For the JIT compiler, [project metropolis](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/metropolis/) aims to minimize the non-Java code used.

Answer (score 2):

`javac` is written in Java, and compiles Java source to bytecode. The source is available online. So `javac` was  bootstrapped.   You may be confusing `javac` with the JVM as the latter is  written in C and is used to compile bytecode to machine code and run it.

Same thing for Python.  The compiler is not the same thing as the execution environment.

Comment: Python has a compiler?

Comment: @saga The terms are fluid when you don’t generate and execute machine code.

Answer (score 0):

With Java, there is the distinction between the Java compiler (`javac`) and the Java Virtual Machine (`java`). Unless an operating system and/or CPU would have support to run Java applications natively, you will need a JVM to run any Java application.

On the other hand, tools such as Apache Maven are written in Java, and invoke the Java compiler as well. This is not done by invoking a Java package. [The page on the Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) describes how this is done, and how you can configure the plugin to use the `javac` executable instead.

There will always be the need for some native code. But nothing is stopping you from writing all of the code that produces Java bytecode in Java itself. After all, what it does is convert text into bytes. You can do that in any programming language, including Java.